# How to set Cookies from Apache Module Code?

Tags: apache

I am coding and Apache Module in C that requires me to Set some cookies on Client's browser from my module say "mod_test.c". How do I efficiently read and set cookies?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set the `Set-Cookie` field in the `headers_out` table and it will set the cookie.

```
    apr_table_add(r->headers_out,"Set-Cookie","doodle=hello");
```

Comment: why all the posts related to Apache C Module are replied by the person that asked the question? Is this technologies so unused?

Comment: are u able to respond to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216799/after-setting-cookie-with-an-apache-module-shall-i-see-the-content-in-chrome?